# android java insertsort using ArrayList

Tags: java, android, algorithm, sorting, arraylist

First of all, I'm writing program to visualize sorting algorithms on Android
I wrote method for insertion sort algorithm. I'm using MPAndroidChart for it.

```
    void insertionSort(int[] arr) {
    int i, j, newValue;
    for (i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
        newValue = arr[i];
        j = i;
        while (j > 0 && arr[j - 1] > newValue) {
            arr[j] = arr[j - 1];
            j--;
        }
        arr[j] = newValue;
    }
}
```

...and it works fine. I want to redesign it to get the same result using ArrayList, but unfortunately, it crashes, and I have no idea why! This is my collection approach insertionSort:

```
void insertionSort(ArrayList<BarEntry> list) {
    int i, j;
    float newValue;
    for (i = 1; i < list.size(); i++) {
        newValue = list.get(i).getY();
        j = i;
        while (j > 0 && list.get(j-1).getY() > newValue) {
            list.set(j, list.get(j-1));
            j--;
        }
        BarEntry be = list.get(list.indexOf(newValue));
        list.set(j, be);
    }
}
```

BarEntry is class used to create charts. I want to sort my data by its Y coordinate, what I do by getY() function. Program shuts down there:

> BarEntry be = list.get(list.indexOf(newValue));
>           list.set(j, be);

**In a nutshell:**
How can I substitute

> arr[j] = newValue;

to collection approach like this (not working):

> list.set(j, list.get(list.indexOf(newValue)));

Comment: Are you getting an exception message? A stacktrace?

Comment: No, my app just getting restarted when I click button which call out my method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You took `newValue` out from `list.get(i)`, and `i` hasn’t changed since, so I believe you can just do that again:

```
    BarEntry be = list.get(i);
```

I have not tested.

I suppose what happened was: `newValue` was the y value from the `BarEntry` you are moving, it’s not the whole `BarEntry`. So `list.indexOf(newValue)` doesn’t find the element and returns `-1`. `list.get(-1)` doesn’t work. Your app crashes.

Comment: Thank you! That was the solution!

Answer (score 0):

From java doc

```
public void add(int index, E element)
```

> Inserts the specified element at the specified position in this list. Shifts the element currently at that position (if any) and any subsequent elements to the right (adds one to their indices).

So no need to shift the rest of the array.

Comment: I have no idea how should it help me.